# Came across this weird error by the debugger. How should I be interpreting this error/warning/log?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-android

These 'warnings' pop up whenever I'm switching a bunch of widgets with `AnimatedSwitcher` ([here's a reproducible example](https://github.com/4amVim/flutter-experiments/tree/be8049b4f870d7a911ceb6e31cc0b14091c1f877)).

Apologies, my google-foo ain't strong enough to find anything on this error.

```dart
Launching lib\main.dart on AC2001 in profile mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-profile.apk (12.1MB).
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52193/9TENt6SK-gs=/ws
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
I/flutter (13798): rebuild scaffold
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb400007747209db0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
W/DisplayEventDispatcher(13798): dispatcher 0xb4000076f7232c70 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
```

Why is this occuring ? and am I to/can I fix them ?